# If $p$ is ramified in a number ring $R$ then $p|\mathrm{disc}(R)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand part of a proof of the following statement, given in Marcus's Number Fields: Let $p$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ ramified in a number ring $R$. Then $p|\mathrm{disc}(R)$.

It goes as follows: Let $P$ be a prime of $R$ lying over $p$ such that $e(P|p)>1$. Then $pR=PI$ with $I$ divisible by all primes of $R$ over $p$. Let $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n$ denote the embeddings of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$ (where $K$ is the number field corresponding to $R$), and extend all $\sigma_i$ to automorphisms of some extension $L$ of $K$ which is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be an integral basis for $R$. Take any $\alpha\in I-pR$. Then $\alpha$ is in every prime of $R$ lying over $p$, but not in $pR$. If we write $\alpha=m_1\alpha_1+\cdots m_n\alpha_n$, $m_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the fact that $\alpha\not\in pR$ means not all the $m_i$ are divisible by $p$. Rearranging if necessary, assume $p\nshortmid m_1$. Set $d=\mathrm{disc}(R)=disc(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$. We have that $disc(\alpha,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)=m_1^2d$. Since $p\nshortmid m_1$, it suffices to show that $p|disc(\alpha,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)$.

Recall that $\alpha$ is in every prime of $R$ over $p$. It follows that $\alpha$ is in every prime of $S=\mathbb{A}\cap L$ lying over $p$. Fixing any prime $Q$ of $S$ lying over $p$, we claim that $\sigma(\alpha)\in Q$ for each automorphisms $\sigma$ of $L$. To see this, notice that $\sigma^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a prime of $\sigma^{-1}(S)=S$ lying over $p$.

I am confused by the last line. Why is $\sigma^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a prime of $\sigma^{-1}(S)=S$ lying over $p$? Are we saying that the ideal generated by $\sigma^{-1}(\alpha)$ is prime in $S$? If so, why is this true? If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, it is a typo and it should be

> To see this, notice that $\sigma^{-1}(Q)$ is a prime of $\sigma^{-1}(S)=S$ lying over $p$.